# C# OleDB, Importing from Excel, bad format

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb

Im importing from Excel to a DataGridView using OleDB.
The cell that i am importing has this string "01/01/2029" but when i import to a DataGridView using OleDB, that string convert to DateTime "01/01/2029 0:00:00" when i want to keep it string with his original format "01/01/2029".
I tried to convert it and a bunch of things, i cant find a solution...
Can anyone find where is the problem?

```
string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string header = "YES";
        string conStr, sheetName;

        conStr = string.Empty;
        switch (extension)
        {

            case ".xls":
                conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header);
                break;

            case ".xlsx":
                conStr = string.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header);
                break;
        }

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    oda.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thats the result im getting https://postimg.cc/sQXJxBCN. The format of the cell in Excel is correct. Is there something i can do to keep the cell format of the Excel when imported, because i think OleDB convert it to DateTime. I tried things like this, but its not converting to string or replacing anything...
```foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { row.Cells[5].Value = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Replace("/01/", "JAN"); }```

Answer (score 0):

As noted from your comment… *”So i can modify it with Replace("/01/", "JAN");”* … this is unnecessary. Rarely would you want to “change” a `DateTime` object to a `string`, this only creates more work for you. You can “format” the grids `DateTime` column to produce just about any date/time type `string` you want to display to the user.

Example… specific to your case, I suggest you set the grids `DateTime` column’s format to something like…

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMM dd, yyyy";
```

Which would produce something like… “Jan 01, 2021”

Or adding an additional “M” to the format…

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
```

Would produce something like… “January 01, 2021”

Comment: Thanks but the format of the date i need is for example "07OCT21".
Thats why i need to convert it to a String, so i can replace "/10/" to "OCT". In my Excel sheet the date format is as follow "07/10/21" and its converted to DateTime "07/10/21 0:00:00" when imported to a DataGridView through OleDB.

Comment: ??? Then change the grids column format to "ddMMMyy". As I mentioned you can make the string date into just about any format you want.

Comment: Not valid, because it displays "07OCT.21" when i need "07OCT21".

Comment: Misread, but anyway its displaying "07OCT.21" when i need "07OCT21". And when i export data to text i get "07/10/2021 0:00:00".

Comment: What does your grid column format look like? It must be adding the "." character.

Comment: _”And when i export data to text i get "07/10/2021 0:00:00"”_ … this is because you are not “FORMATTING” the `DateTime` string. As mentioned numerous times and I am not sure what part of this you are missing… _“**but you can format the date string to just about ANY format you want**”_ … when exporting the `DateTme` object try something like… `DateTimeObject.ToString(“ddMMMyy”);`